# redirect query string part if it's put after extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using ultimate seo url in zen cart framework. I have a two type of URL structure which needs to be redirected.

1) `http://www.naturaflowers.com/anemones/wedding-anemone-flowers.html?somestring`
to

```
http://www.naturaflowers.com/anemones/wedding-anemone-flowers.html
```

2)  (*** In this case when parameter only /?page=1) just like following

`http://www.naturaflowers.com/wholesale-flowers.html?page=1` to

```
http://www.naturaflowers.com/wholesale-flowers.html
```

can't figure out. Any help will be appreciated. Please!!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?somestring
RewriteRule ^(anemones/wedding-anemone-flowers.html)$ /$1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?page=1($|&)
RewriteRUle ^(wholesale-flowers.html)$ /$1? [L,R]
```